# Is there a class just for reading excel file using Laravel Excel?

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-10, laravel-excel

I've a laravel 10 project. And I'm using [Laravel Excel](https://github.com/SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel) Package.

I read the documentation, it's divided into `Imports` and `Exports`. There isn't any mention for just reading the file. I mean, I know we can make adjustments in `Imports`, but I wanted to know any proper standard way just for reading the file & manipulating data.

Is there a way we can just create a class file for multiple Spreedsheets like it's being done for `Imports` and `Exports`, just for reading and manipulating data, rather than importing it to database?

Comment: If you installed Laravel Excel that installs PHPOffice so you can use that ([docs](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-and-writing-to-file/))

Comment: As it says on that github page, this is a wrapper around the PhpSpreadsheet library.  https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/: _"PhpSpreadsheet is a library written in pure PHP and offers a set of classes that allow you to read and write various spreadsheet file formats such as Excel and LibreOffice Calc."_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer:**

Here is a solution to read and manipulate data from spreadsheet files directly in Laravel using the Laravel Excel package. This is particularly useful when you need to work with data from Excel files without importing them into a database.

**Step 1: Install Laravel Excel**

```bash
composer require maatwebsite/excel
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

// Read the Excel file
$excelSpreadSheetData = Excel::toCollection(null, 'your-spreadsheet.xlsx');

// In `$excelSpreadSheetData`, you get all the sheets available in your Excel file.
// Suppose that in your Excel file, there are 3 sheets (User, Employee, Salary).
// You can access the data like this:

$userData = $excelSpreadSheetData[0];
$employeeData = $excelSpreadSheetData[1];
$salaryData = $excelSpreadSheetData[2];
```

This approach allows you to work directly with data from Excel files in Laravel, and it can be useful for tasks that don't involve importing data into a database.

I hope this helps anyone looking to work with Excel data in Laravel.